# SQL Pivot with dynamic values for IN CLAUSE

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

I have a table in the below format

**Details**

```
+-------------------+--------+------------+----------------+-------+
| LOB               | Level  | Year_Month | Classification | Count |
+-------------------+--------+------------+----------------+-------+
| Mergers& Acqu     | Level3 | 2020-05    | Statement      | 356   |
+-------------------+--------+------------+----------------+-------+
| Wealth Management | Level2 | 2020-05    | Lending        | 23    |
+-------------------+--------+------------+----------------+-------+
| Finance           | Level3 | 2020-06    | Statement      | 65    |
+-------------------+--------+------------+----------------+-------+
```

How do I pivot the Year_month column having the count?

**Expected result**

```
+-------------------+--------+----------------+---------+---------+
| LOB               | Level  | Classification | 2020-05 | 2020-06 |
+-------------------+--------+----------------+---------+---------+
| Mergers& Acqu     | Level3 | Statement      | 356     | 0       |
+-------------------+--------+----------------+---------+---------+
| Wealth Management | Level2 | Lending        | 23      | 0       |
+-------------------+--------+----------------+---------+---------+
| Finance           | Level3 | Statement      | 0       | 65      |
+-------------------+--------+----------------+---------+---------+
```

I tried the below query but I don't get the desired result

```
SELECT * FROM DETAILS
PIVOT (SUM(Count) FOR YEAR_MONTH IN (SELECT distinct YEAR_MONTH FROM DETAILS))
```

How can I make the IN CLAUSE have dynamic values instead of preset values?

Comment: You can use dynamic SQL: https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4471013000346257238

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option which uses a substitution variable:

```
SQL> set verify off
SQL> clear columns
columns cleared
SQL> column llist new_value slist
SQL> select listagg(ym, ', ') within group (order by ym) as llist
  2  from (select distinct
  3          chr(39) || year_month ||chr(39) || ' as "' || year_month ||'"' ym
  4        from details
  5      );

LLIST
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'2020-05' as "2020-05", '2020-06' as "2020-06"

SQL> select * from
  2  (select lob, clevel, classification, year_month, ccount from details)
  3     pivot (sum(ccount)
  4            for year_month in (&slist));

LOB               CLEVEL CLASSIFIC    2020-05    2020-06
----------------- ------ --------- ---------- ----------
Finance           level3 statement                    65
Wealth Management level2 lending           23
Mergers and Acqu  level3 statement        356

SQL>
```

Its *drawback* is that it'll fail if `LISTAGG`'s result is longer than 4000 characters (but, then again, what will you do with a result that contains more than 500 months?).

Answer (score 0):

Oracle does not support dynamic values in the `IN` clause of a `PIVOT` function unless you are using `PIVOT XML`.  When running a query, Oracle needs it to always have the same number of columns.

Here is an example of your query if you were to use `PIVOT XML`

```
WITH
    details (lob_val,
             level_val,
             year_month,
             classification,
             COUNT)
    AS
        (SELECT 'Mergers& Acqu', 'Level3', '2020-05', 'Statement', 356 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Wealth Management', 'Level2', '2020-05', 'Lending  ', 23 FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'Finance', 'Level3', '2020-06', 'Statement', 65 FROM DUAL)
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT lob_val, level_val, year_month, classification, COUNT FROM details)
       PIVOT XML (SUM (COUNT) AS sum_count
                 FOR (year_month)
                 IN (SELECT DISTINCT year_month
                       FROM details));
```